# How to apply defined functions to arrays in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, function

I have two functions: `time_reversal` which reverses my time component "n" ; and  `time_shift`, which shifts my time coordinate "n" in a "k" quantity. These are the functions:

```
#time_reversal    

def time_reversal(n):                              
        ind = arange(n.size-1,-1,-1)                   
        n_r=n[ind]                                     
        return n_r                                        
# time_shift                                          
def time_shift(n,k):                               
        N=n.size                                          
        if k>=0:                                          
           N_ts=concatenate( (zeros(k),n[0:N-k]), 0)  
        else:                                              
           k=-k                                             
        N_ts=concatenate( (n[k:N],zeros(k)), 0)    
        return N_ts
```

Given the equation : `y[n]=y[n]+x[k]*h[n-k]`
I need to apply this equations to the "h" array. I need to reverse "n" and shift it a "k" quantity. The array "x" stays un touched.

The problem is that I don't know how to apply those functions to my problem. I tried to substitute "n_r" and "N_ts" like this :`y[n]=y[n]+x[k]*h[n_r-N_ts]` but it gives me errors.
EDIT :PROGRAM

```
from numpy import*
from matplotlib.pyplot import*

x=array([2,1,-1])
h=array([1,2,1,0,1,2,1])
y=array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])

def time_reversal(n):                              
        ind = arange(n.size-1,-1,-1)                   
        n_r=n[ind]                                     
        return n_r                                        

def time_shift(n,k):                               
        N=n.size                                          
        if k>=0:                                          
           N_ts=concatenate( (zeros(k),n[0:N-k]), 0)  
        else:                                              
           k=-k                                             
        N_ts=concatenate( (n[k:N],zeros(k)), 0)    
        return N_ts  

for n in range(0,9):
     for k in range(0,3):                                       
        y[n]=y[n]+x[k]*h[n_r-N_ts]                         
print("y = ",y)
```

It says that n_r and N_ts are not defined for some reason.

Comment: Please provide the errors and code you used to generate in your question [mcve]. It's difficult to follow your explanation, but it looks like you've translated MATLAB code for a convolution into numpy

Comment: y(n) is the con volution of x and h and I can get the result typing  this: 
y=convolve(x,h, mode="full"). But, Im also asked to do the convolution using those two defined functions

Comment: `res = list(map(lambda i: i+x[k]*h[n_r-Nts], h))` what happens if you do this?

Comment: NameError: name 'n_r' is not defined

Comment: This should be the result : y = [ 2  5  3 -1  1  5  3 -1 -1];n=9 and k=3 because x has only three elements.

Comment: you never call any of your functions to get `n_r` nor define it outside your functions, `n_r` is not created

Comment: you never declare `n_r` or `Nts`, only within your functions, and you don't call either `time_reversal` or `time_shift` to get their values, you need to take a step back before you are working on calculations

Comment: So how do you use , for example, the n_r function so the "h" array reverses the "n component"?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure if this is what you want, but there is something called the `map` function that allows you to apply a function to each element of an array and return a new array containing the results.  For example:

```
def add2(n):
    return n + 2

lst = [1, 2, 3]
print(list(map(add2, lst))) # convert from map object to list
```

The resulting list is `[3, 4, 5]`.

Hope this helps.